# Binormal operator - equivalent definitions?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have seen two different definitions of a binormal operator A.

1. A is unitarily equivalent to a block 2x2 matrix of commuting normal matrices.
2. AA* commutes with A*A.

I am hoping these definitions are equivalent, but I can not see the proof. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies the first definition but not the second.